# De-normalization/ Inverse normalize

Tags: excel-formula, normalization, denormalization

So I have normalized some data in Excel to the range of 0-1, using the following formula

(B6-MIN(B$6:B$370))/(MAX(B$6:B$370)-MIN(B$6:B$370)) 
what I would like to know is how would one go about doing the inverse of the formula above or any other method of reverting back to an de-normalized state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've posted, the cell `B6` is being normalized against the column `B`.  So to de-normalize, it would just be

```
=B6
```

If you want to take some arbitrary value between 0 and 1, (e.g., 0.3), you'd just invert the formula algebraically:

```
= 0.3 * (MAX(B$6:B$370) - MIN(B$6:B$370)) + MIN(B$6:B$370)
```

To do this with a cell (e.g., `D9`), it would be the same, just using the cell number instead of a value:

```
= D9 * (MAX(B$6:B$370) - MIN(B$6:B$370)) + MIN(B$6:B$370)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, that seems to have done the trick.